# asp.net: monitor user click

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I'm trying to fire an event when a user clicks a hyperlink. But it would complain that the event is not defined:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" onmouseover="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server">www.google.com</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:Button
    id="btnSubmit"
    Text="Submit"
    Runat="server"  />
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSubmit.Text = "clicked a link!!!";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems.

1. You do not have any sort of click event setup on your hyperlink.  You do have a "onmouseover" but based on [MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink_events.aspx) there is no click event for that control.
2. You have a button defined, but no events associated with that button.
3. You have a function that appears to be an event handler, but the naming convention suggests that it is associated with the button that has no events.

Can you provide more detail of what you are trying to do?  I assume the c# code you have posted resides in the code behind?

Update:

Try changing your code to this -

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_Link" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="www.google.com" runat="server" />
```

Obviously this will not redirect you, but based on what your code does, it doesn't sound like you want a redirect...

Comment: 1. I changed onmouseover to onclick, the same error would show up
2. the button has the same onclick="btnSubmit_click" event
3. yes it is.

Comment: There is no OnClick event for the asp.net hyperlink control.  I would suggest using a LinkButton if you need onclick.

Comment: The whole point is to fire an event on user click a asp:hyperlink. So you mean it cannot be done?

Comment: Interesting, have you tried your code? It still has the same error: Error: 'btnSubmit_Click' is undefined

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace `onmouseover` with `OnClick`.  Try it now

Answer (score 1):

The event you're trying to trigger is a server side event. You need to use client side code for what you want to do. Plus, there is no property known as onmouseover, you can add it as a client side event from code behind

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","yourClientFunction");//this can be done in page load
```

Comment: Why does he need to use client side code for what he wants to do?

Comment: Because hyperLink does not cause postbacks, so either he use it with clientside code, or use something like LinkButton

Comment: I've tried to add the following code to page_load, it still has the same error. protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "btnSubmit_Click");//this can be done in page load 
        }

Comment: I mean use it with a javascript function, not with the C# event, or use LinkButton which have onClick property and which can cause postBack